# Getting the previous camera Latitude and Longitude on Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Im currently working with google maps on my android app and i need to compare distances when the camera is moved. I can get the current camera latitude and longitude by using the onCameraChange method, however, im struggling with getting the cameras previous latitude and longitude. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: You can save the previous data and then call it back again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see an existing API to get [previous location with Google Maps Camera position api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#the_camera_position)

You can create a `prevLat`, and `prevLong` variables. The first time your app starts, in initialization, save the location in these variables. Use these to calculate the distance in `onCameraChange`, and then update the `prevLat, prevLang` with current location at the end of `onCameraChange`.